# SelectedValue not updating when set in code

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I can see this question has been asked before but nothing seems to work for me.

I have a wpf desktop app.

i have this comboBox:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users, Mode=TwoWay,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" DisplayMemberPath="Value.Login"
   SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedManagerUser, 
   Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  
   SelectedValuePath="Value"  
   IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  />
```

The data source is a dictionary object:

```
public Dictionary<string,UserRecord> Users
{
    get
    {
       //get data
    }
    set { _Users =  value; RaisePropertyChanged(Constants.VM_Users); }
}
```

I add a new entry in my MVVM and update the data.

I then set the selected item in my mvvm:

```
private UserRecord _selectedManagerUser;
public UserRecord SelectedManagerUser 
{ 
    get
    {
        return _selectedManagerUser;
    }
    set
    {
        _selectedManagerUser = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedManagerUser");
    }
}
SelectedManagerUser = Users[temp];

public class UserRecord : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _Active;
    private int _UserRecordId;
    private string _UserRef;
    private string _FName;
    private string _SName;
    private string _Login;
    private string _Salt;
    private int _IsAdmin;
    private string _FullName;
    private string _Branch;
    private string _Position;
    private string _Department;

    public int Disabled { get { return _Active; } set { _Active = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Active); } }
    public int UserRecordId { get { return _UserRecordId; } set { _UserRecordId = value; RaisePropertyChanged("UserRecordId"); } }
    public string UserRef { get { return _UserRef; } set { _UserRef = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_UserRef); } }
    public string FName { get { return _FName; } set { _FName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_FName); } }
    public string SName { get { return _SName; } set { _SName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_SName); } }
    public string Login { get { return _Login; } set { _Login = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Login); } }
    public string Salt { get { return _Salt; } set { _Salt = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Salt); } }
    public int IsAdmin { get { return _IsAdmin; } set { _IsAdmin = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_IsAdmin); } }
    public string Branch { get { return _Branch; } set { _Branch = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Branch); } }
    public string Position { get { return _Position; } set { _Position = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Position); } }
    public string Department { get { return _Department; } set { _Department = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Department); } }
    public string FullName { get { return FName + ", " + SName; } set { _FullName = value; RaisePropertyChanged(InformedWorkerCommon.Constants.VM_Fullname); } }
}
```

I know the new item has been added because -

1. I can see it int  the dropdown
2. I set a breakpoint in my code and inspect.

The combo box  just displays an empty value.

Anything else I can try?

thanks

Comment: What is `temp`?

Comment: hi, sorry yes, temp is the new key I created and is derived from a textbox. Again, the key is valid

Comment: I guess the problem is that your new key/value is not in the Users Collection. You must have in mind that combobox won't get notifyed on any new items in the Users collection, only when a new collection is setted in `Users`

Comment: @Pikoh Like I said in my question it IS populated which is why i am posting the question

Comment: Well, then i can't think in anything else. Maybe if you could prepare a example we could try we could have a look at it.

Comment: @Pikoh hi, thanks for all your time.  Apart from creating a project and posting it the code is as you can see it. However, i do appreciate that there is a mental dead-end here.  I stripped everything back in my code and I set break-points everywhere to inspect values and I have been observant in my output window for binding errors and nothing is amiss. This issue does not appear if I do NOT use a dictionary object so all I can think of is the usage of the dictionary object. But, when reading the selectedvalue back after the user manually selects presents no problems so just weird ... (

Comment: and depressing. But its xmas!

Comment: You're not just missing a PropertyChanged call on SelectedManagerUser are you?

Comment: @IanofOz thanks, i did set a breakpoint on that call and it is being hit

Comment: Cool, helps to have the whole picture in the question now. I think your IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem may get confused by binding to a dictionary. Try removing it to see if your new entry turns up. It may be enough, although you may need to take a non-dictionary approach.

Comment: @IanofOz nice idea but did not work. what a pain lol thanks

Comment: Well, i don't understand. I've created a sample project and for me it works just fine...

Comment: The problem might be that the `UserRecord` in the `SelectedManagerUser` property does not compare equal to the desired dictionary `Value`. Either you override the `Equals` method of UserControl, or you assign a UserControl that already exists as `Value` in the dictionary.

Comment: @Pikoh hmmm. then that would indicate the problem is with me.  the only thing I have not stated is that I am using devcomponent controls...

Comment: @Clemens thanks worth check the value objec then. the only thing i have not done thanks

Comment: Also, setting `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is redundant on both Bindings. Just as `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem`.

Comment: @Clemens I was getting depserate :)

Comment: Well, I just read `SelectedManagerUser = Users[temp];`. That should work of course (and does for me).

Comment: @Clemens checke value object and is identical. I shall try it with a 'normal' wpf control

Comment: Yes,try with a normal combobox,as for me it's working perfecly

Comment: Dictionaries are TERRIBLE for databinding.  Just awful.  If you need a keyed collection and you want to bind against it, create a custom collection extending KeyedCollection.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx With some extra work TItem can implement INPC (make the key read only, tho) and the collection can implement INCC.  Works great for binding.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what's going wrong on your side, but it might be helpful to look at a working solution.

XAML:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}"
          DisplayMemberPath="Value.Name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedUser}"  
          SelectedValuePath="Value" />
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Loaded += WindowLoaded;

        var vm = new ViewModel();
        vm.Users.Add("u1", new UserRecord { Name = "User 1" });
        vm.Users.Add("u2", new UserRecord { Name = "User 2" });
        vm.Users.Add("u3", new UserRecord { Name = "User 3" });
        DataContext = vm;
    }

    private void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // make sure it works after DataContext was set
        var vm = (ViewModel)DataContext;
        vm.SelectedUser = vm.Users["u2"];
    }
}

public class UserRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Dictionary<string, UserRecord> Users { get; }
        = new Dictionary<string, UserRecord>();

    private UserRecord selectedUser;
    public UserRecord SelectedUser
    {
        get { return selectedUser; }
        set
        {
            selectedUser = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this,
                new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedUser)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks have to pop out but will yet when back

Comment: hi, i am back. will look at this now. i will adopt your code and work back to wards mine stuff.  I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: This did work for me but not for when the UserRecord had many different properties as opposed to just the one field you had.I managed to solve the problem by binding a selected index and using that to select it.

Comment: hi, yes i would tend to agree with you. But for some reason it does. My code is pretty bare bones

Comment: @AndrewSimpson I've tried in my example with 3 properties in `UserRecord` (2 string,1 int). It also worked flawless..

Comment: well i am totally baffled then. I updated my question with the UserRecord class. I shall keep on plugging away at it. Though, apart from the extra properties it is identical to yours apart from the data soiurce which is from an sql lite db.  But like i said when i inspect the new values of that collection when I added the new entry it exists but does not select. It does with an observable collection and it does whrn I select the index. A nit flumoxed as to what to try next - apart fro reimsyalling vs2015

Answer (score 0):

Your SelectedManagerUser property should be changed to this. The SelectedManagerUser property is set with new value but you do not raise that event so the UI will not be updated.

```
    private UserRecord _selectedManagerUser;
    public UserRecord SelectedManagerUser 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _selectedManagerUser;
        }
        set
        {
            _selectedManagerUser = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedManagerUser");
        }
    }
```

Comment: kim, thanks. My fault the cod ei posted for that property i just abbreviated. I have what you have. But thanks

Comment: If your .NET version is not too old, `RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedManagerUser))` also works

Answer (score 0):

Download `Prism` from `Nuget` and inherit your class from `BindableBase`.

After it use this:

```
private UserRecord selectedManagerUser;

public UserRecord SelectedManagerUser
{
    get { return this.selectedManagerUser; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.selectedManagerUser, value); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of two things can cause this.  First, it might be because you're not setting `SelectedManagerUser` to be an instance of `UserRecord` that is NOT in the Dictionary, or that Dictionaries still suck for databinding.  Lemme cover them both.

When you work with `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` bindings, if you want `SelectedItem` changes to be reflected in the UI, you must set it to an instance that can be found within `ItemsSource`.  The control, by default, will look for the item in the source that is referentially equal to the selected item.  I'm 99% sure it will use `IEquatable<T>` instead of reference checking if your items implement it.

If that's not your problem, then it's because Dictionaries suck for databinding.

Dictionaries are TERRIBLE for databinding.  Just awful.  If you need a keyed collection and you want to bind against it, create a custom collection extending [KeyedCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx). With some extra work TItem can implement INPC (make the key read only, tho) and the collection can implement INCC.  Works great for binding.  Why do I mention this?  Read on...

*Your problem* is that, within the ComboBox, `SelectedItem` is actually of type `KeyValuePair<string,UserRecord>`, and NOT `UserRecord`.  So the binding will NOT work.  If you grab a copy of Snoop and examine the bindings at runtime, you'll see this.

The problem is that the control doesn't know jack squat about Dictionaries.  All it knows is `IEnumerable<T>`.  `Dictionary<K,T>` implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<K,T>>`, so the control creates an item for each key value pair.  SelectedItem is also a key value pair.  So, when you bind that to a property of type `UserRecord`, yes it is able to use the SelectedValuePath to set the value properly, *but it cannot (does not) [ninja edit: unless this behavior has changed over the past few years :/] iterate the enumerable in order to find the correct key value pair when you set the value in your view model*.

If `UserRecord`'s key value is a property within the type, then definitely create a KeyedCollection for it.  `KeyedCollection<Tkey,TItem>` implements 'IEnumerable` so it works seamlessly with bindings.  If not, wrap it in a proxy, or add the property.

And when I say "wrap it in a proxy", anybody who says "what, like a KeyValuePair?" I'm going to punch you through the internet.  The proxy becomes the value you bind against.  Don't waste your time with this `SelectedValuePath` nonsense.  Work with the proxies directly.  When you need your value, extract it at the last moment, not immediately after the binding executes.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't agree with this. Have a look at @Clemens answer (I have a similar example myself) and the binding works just fine.

Comment: @Pikoh Hmmm, I haven't used them for quite a few framework releases, so they *might* have changed the ItemsControl behavior regarding Dictionaries.  If that is the case, then it might be because he's not handling his references properly.  Edited to include the other possibility.  Thanks.

Comment: You must have in mind that OP is not using `SelectedItem`,but `SelectedValue` with `SelectedValuePath=value`. That makes that `SelectedManagerUser` is of type `UserRecord`.

Comment: @Pikoh Yes, I know, but that could very well be part of his problem.  I have no code (and I do scream) because I haven't spun up a prototype to re-examine databinding against a dictionary.  But this approach (SelectedValuePath and such) is needlessly complex and much more prone to issues with databinding (as OP has amply illustrated).  That's essentially what I mean by *Don't waste your time with this SelectedValuePath nonsense*

Comment: I agree with that,your solution is cleaner (I'd never use a Dictionary for binding, i'm used to ObservableCollections). But OP code SHOULD work, I have a sample that works with that code, and just to test i've tried targeting .net 4.0 and it still works.

Comment: @Pikoh Heh, I haven't used Dictionaries in bindings since 3.0 :)

Comment: Well..that's a long time ago. Did WPF existed in that framework version? :)

Comment: @Pikoh brand spanking new.  *cue "a whole new world"*